# Magento 2 Migration From custom tables (non-magento) to magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to use the Magento 2 Data Migration tool in order to make the tool believe that my woocommerce database is actually M1 database.

I do this by creating views.
I commented out all steps so that only customers migrated.

However I get the error :

> [2017-05-15 18:58:25][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step:
>   Stage]: started 78% [======================>-----] Remaining Time: 1
>   sec
>
> [Zend_Db_Statement_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1347
>   'woo.customer_entity' is not BASE TABLE, query was: CREATE TRIGGER
>   trg_customer_entity_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON customer_ent   ity
>   FOR EACH ROW   BEGIN   INSERT INTO m2_cl_customer_entity (`entity_id`,
>   `operation`) VALUES (NEW.entity_id, 'INSERT')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>   operation = 'INSERT';   END
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1347
>   'woo.customer_entity' is not BASE TABLE

I have been told that tool is really customizable and can be used for any db to m2 migration.

What am I missing out on the above. Should I just create a table ?

Comment: It looks that somehow the migration tool thinks that your woocommerce customer table is called `customer_entity`. I don't know where to adjust this, though. But i fear that creating a new table won't help